# Mono process consumes large memory

Tags: c#, linux, memory, mono

I have a console program which when run on **`Windows`** never crosses `300MB` of memory usage. However, when it run under Linux using `Mono runtime`, it crosses over `1GB` within 10-15 minutes and keeps on increasing gradually.

I am not able to figure out the reason. I tried playing with `MONO_GC_PARAMS` like `nursery-size=32m,major=marksweep-conc,stack-mark=precise` but doesn't seem to make any difference.

I am using **`Mono 4.4`** and the garbage collector is **`SGen`**.

Any further inputs to narrow down the problem is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What's the **exact** version of mono you're using? there are 5 git tags in mono that start with "4.4". Also, what version of Linux is this (distro and version), and how did you install mono on it? have you tried compiling mono v4.5 yourself to see if there's improvement or it's even worse?